# Can Google Spreadsheet send Firefox or Chrome notifications

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-sheets, alerts

I have a question regarding Chrome and/or Firefox notifications regarding Google Spreadsheets.

So let's say that I have a cell that contains the following text:

```
1-10-1
```

or

```
1-9-0
```

Anything in that sort.

Can Google Spreadsheet be optimized to send me a Chrome or Firefox notification if the text would contain 10, 11 or 12?

So in code something like:

```
=IF(OR(REGEXMATCH(A1,"10"),REGEXMATCH(A1,"11"),REGEXMATCH(A1,"12")), SENDCHROMENOTIFICATION("ALERT"),//do nothing)
```

Or I would even be happy with an e-mail notification.

Hard to search Google as results are very much related to document update notifications (by other people), so nothing related to programmatic alerts.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript function (Tools > Script Editor):

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailBody);
```

I can do all the text processing with script as well.

And add a timed trigger.